# GWT works on localhost, but shows 404 on remote tomcat

Tags: gwt, tomcat, deployment

I use eclipse's GWT toolkit to compile my project. And I deploy it in my localhost, it works. But when I upload it to a remote tomcat, it shows 404. I use `GWT.getHostPageBaseURL()` to get the host URL.
In the local tomcat, url is `localhost:8080/M/M.html`. In the remote tomcat, it is `http://p.i.edu:8080/M/M.html`

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem.what is worse,my project delopyed can not start at all.When I check it by tomcat manager,I got the negative infos as below:
FAIL - Application at context path /GwtTest could not be started
FAIL - Encountered exception org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/GwtTest]]

Several days before ,I deploy a similar one (without any changes just creating it by Eclipse)successfully to the same remote tomcat.
I checked the project files carefully,and now confirm the cause is in web.xml.I defined a servlet in it,but the remote tomcat seems to be unknown it.After change the server-class's content to any(even wrone),the 404 is gone,but the servlet can not work! while on local windows tomcat,the servlet works fine!

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
GWT.getModuleBaseUrl();
```

It will return you the complete url your are looking for. I hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: It still does not work. In the local tomcat, url is http://localhost:8080/M/M.html. In the remote tomcat, it is http://p.i.edu:8080/M/M.html

Comment: Sorry, would you mind to elaborate your question what actually you want?